# Active Records - Where conditions on a has_one model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

If I have the following has_one setup:

```
class Account
 has_one :user
```

How can I do something like @account.user.where(:visible => true)

Or more specifically, how do I call conditions on a has_one relationship in a similar way to a has_many? I'm currently using a scope on the user which seems silly?

```
def is_visible?
  if self.visible
    return self 
  else
    return false
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're wanting to get a list of accounts where the user is visible?

Comment: Disco. Yes, that's it. But I can't seem to call @account.user.where(:visible => true) and I am unsure why.

Comment: Do you want this condition to be applied in all the associations?

Comment: No, sometimes I'll want to fetch all without any conditions, so I can't just default_scope it directly.

Comment: also, you don't need an `is_visible?` method. ActiveRecord already gives you a `visible?` method if the column `"visible"` is a `boolean`.

Comment: Had no idea active record did that. That's an awesome tip, thanks!

Comment: You get the question mark methods no matter what type of variable the column is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a join to get the list of visible user accounts, but it's not too hard once you grok the query. Try this:

```
@accounts = Account.joins(:user).where(:users => {:visible => true})
```

You could also easily encapsulate it into a scope.

```
scope :with_visible_user, joins(:user).where(:users => {:visible => true})

@accounts = Account.with_visible_user
```